# Leaflet - Remove label from map

Tags: label, leaflet, unbind

I am adding a labels ona leaflet map like this:

```
label = new L.Label()
label.setContent("static label")
label.setLatLng(polygon.getBounds().getCenter())
map.showLabel(label);
```

How can I delete it?
I tried:

```
label.close();
label.onRemove(map);
label.unbindLabel();
```

No success with any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `label` a kind of unconventionally. Normally you would add it to the polygon using the `bindLabel` method, where it also has the `unbindLabel` method to remove it. But you're using the `showLabel` method of `L.Map`, which in fact does nothing else use the `addLayer` method of `L.Map`. Weirdly enough there is no `hideLabel` method added to `L.Map` so you need to use the `removeLayer` function of `L.Map`:

```
map.removeLayer(label);
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/28yohU?p=preview

Answer (score -2):

Consider using the property attributionControl

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    //[...]
    attributionControl: false
    //[...]
});
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution